# Compared results of 2 goodness-of-fit chi-square test

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, frequency

I am conducting `Goodness-of-fit` test on 2 cities using chi square.

```
                  | Males    Females
                  | --------------
Test 1 : Boston   | 50000    10000
say chi square = 29.45 with df=1
```

Similiarly,

```
                  | Males     Females
                  | --------------
Test 2 : NYC      | 500000    20000
say chi square = 455.45 with df=1
```

Can I say since chi-square for NYC was much higher than that of Boston, the 'unknown' relationship between city and sex ratio is stronger in NYC than Boston?

Comment: If you are trying to compare Boston with NYC, why not do a 2x2 chi-square?

Comment: @PeterFlom That would be a test-of-independence for me and it may prove that over all city and sec ratio are not independent.  My objective is to prove that NYC and sex ratio relationship is somehow stronger than that in Boston.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an argument about the relationship being 'stronger' you would need to compare an effect size (such as a difference in proportions, for example, or perhaps better a log odds-ratio) rather than just the chi-square itself, which may not actually tell you directly about the strength of relationship, since it as affected by the sample size.

A comparison of difference in proportions would lead you to the effect size in a two-sample proportions test (equivalently a 2x2 chi-square).

A comparison of log-odds might be done in several ways; an asymptotic normal approximation is discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio#Statistical_inference)